# MVC 4: add "Index" to url path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

For some specific reasons I need .NET MVC 4 not to remove "Index" automatically from the URL. Basically I need to convert

http ://example.com/ to http ://example.com/Index

or

http ://example.com/foo to http ://example.com/foo/Index

The problem is that @URL.Action("Index", "Foo") just outputs /Foo, I need it to output Foo/Index.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to remove the default action from your route mapping.

So instead of this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Just take out `action = "Index"`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Default",
  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```